# Files created below an umounted mount point

Tags: unix, filesystems, solaris

We have a Solaris system running a pair of servers as as Active/Passive cluster.  At any given time, only 1 of the two is running our applications.

On each, we have a mount point "/foo" .  We have a SAN filesystem "bar" that is mounted on /foo on whichever server is active at the time.  bar/ has a hierarchy of files for various services.

One of the teams have created files and directories on the underlying directory /foo even though bar was not mounted at the time.  Whenever bar is mounted onto /foo , these files are hidden underneath the real files of bar.

I am trying to find a reference that says it is A Bad Practice to create files and directories below an unmounted mount point.  Can anybody provide such a reference?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a reference?  Best case, creating files like that is using disk storage for something that can't normally be read, which is totally useless.  Anyone who needs a reference that something like this isn't good has to be pretty much totally incapable of independent thought.

Comment: I'm in a big convoluted enterprise environment.  The middleware team created this problem.  It confuses the monitoring team so that they think both nodes are active even though I know only 1 is.  I am trying to persuade the App Owner that it is a Bad Practice, so they will direct middleware to fix their errors.  So the "reference" that I seek it my proof to the App Owner that it should be fixed.

Comment: *It confuses the monitoring team so that they think both nodes are active* If that in itself isn't sufficient to convince your app team what they're doing is brain-dead, I don't know what to say.  Test what happens if you take write permission from the mount point away from them - unmount the filesystem, and make the mount directory `0755 root:root`. Remount the filesystem on that directory and see if the app has proper write permissions.Problem fixed. If they can't play nice, put them into a playpen. You probably should do that anyway, if only because the app could fill up a disk it shouldn't